# MySQL Empty Cells In Normalised Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization

OK, Last post on this subject (I hope). I've been trying to look into normalisation for tables in a website that I've been building and I have to be honest that I've struggled with it, however after my last post it seems that I may have finally grasped it and set my tables properly.

However, one question remains.  If I create a table that is seemingly in 3rd normal form, is it acceptable to have areas of white space or empty cells if the data is relevant to that specific table? Let me give you an example:

On a news website I have an `Authors_Table`

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| ID | FIRSTNAME | SURNAME  | EMAIL           | BIO ( REQUIRED )  | TWITTER | FACEBOOK | WEBSITE |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 01 | Brian     | Griffin  | brian@gmail.com | About me...       | URL     |          | URL     |
| 02 | Meg       | Griffin  | meg@gmail.com   | About me...       | URL     |          |         |
| 03 | Peter     | Griffin  | peter@gmail.com | About me...       |         | URL      | URL     |
| 04 | Glen      | Quagmire | glen@gmail.com  | About me...       | URL     | URL      |         |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

This would be used on the `article` page to give a little details about who has written it, which is very common in newspapers and on modern blogs.  Now the last 3 columns `Facebook, Twitter, Website` are obviously relevant to the Author & therefore to the PK (`ID`). As you know though, not everyone has either twitter or a wesbite or facebook so the content of these cells is rather flexible so obviously empty cells will occur in some cases.

It was suggested to do it another way so I produced:

Links

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID | TYPE              |
+----+-------------------+
| 01 | Facebook          |
| 02 | Twitter           |
| 03 | Website           |
+----+-------------------+
```

Author_Links

```
+----------+--------+------+
| AUTHOR   | TYPE   | LINK |
+----------+--------+------+
| 01       | 01     | URL  |
| 01       | 02     | URL  |
| 01       | 03     | URL  |
| 02       | 02     | URL  |
| 02       | 03     | URL  |
| 03       | 01     | URL  |
+----------+--------+------+
```

Now I understand the concept of this however isn't it just as "correct" to have and to use the original table. Updates can be made using a form & php to say:

```
$update_link_sql = "UPDATE authours SET facebook = ' NEW VALUE ' WHERE id = '$author_id'";
$update_link_res = mysqli_query($con, $update_links_sql);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's "correct" to store "optional" attributes as columns in the entity table. It's just when we have repeated values, e.g. multiple facebook pages for an author, for example, that we'd want to implement the child table. (We don't want to store "repeating" attributes in the entity table.)

As long as there's a restriction in the model, that an attribute will be limited to a single value (a single facebook page, a single twitter, etc.) those attributes can be stored in the entity table. We'd just use a `NULL` value to indicate that a value is not present.

One benefit of the separate table approach (outlined in your post) is that it would be "easier" to add a new "type" of URL. For example, if in the future we want to store a blogspot URL, or an instagram URL, instead of having to modify the entity table to add new columns, we can simply add rows to the "link_type" table and "author_link" table. That's the big benefit there.

Answer (score 1):

As for me Authors_Table is correct.

```
| ID | FIRSTNAME | SURNAME | EMAIL | BIO ( REQUIRED ) | TWITTER | FACEBOOK | WEBSITE |
```

The **only reason** to have three tables:

Authors

```
| ID | FIRSTNAME | SURNAME  | EMAIL | BIO ( REQUIRED )  |
```

Link_types

```
| ID | TYPE |
```

Author_links

```
| AUTHOR_ID | LINK_TYPE_ID | URL |
```

...is that your authors could have more than one link of specific type (for example two twitter accounts, btw, is it legal?)

If we suppose that any author can have no more than one account of each type - your version with single table is correct.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me as it is useful for another table that I have normalised too.  What do you mean by `legal`?

Comment: @user3177012: I think he meant by "legal", whether or not the twitter terms of service allow for an individual to have more than one twitter account.

Comment: Ah right @spencer7593, you are probably right. Who would ever have multiple twitter accounts? lol

Answer (score 1):

Either way is acceptable depending on functional requirements.

If you need to dynamically add more url types/fields to profile then use latter.

If there is ever going to be only 3 then former is better.

No need to over-engineer.